# Passing event from Javascript to dart method in browser

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

This is my html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk">
    <title>quickstart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script defer src="allEvents.js"></script>
    <script defer src="main.dart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

allEvents.js file:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("from event");
  var event = new CustomEvent("test", { "detail": "Example of an event" });
  window.document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Dart main method:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main() {
  print("from  main");
  html.window.onMessage.listen((html.MessageEvent event) {
    print("hello dart");
  });
}
```

I am not able to get test event in my dart hence no console log, what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main() {
  print("from  main");
  html.CustomEvent someEvent;
  html.window.document.addEventListener(
      'test',
      (event) =>
          {someEvent = event as html.CustomEvent, print(someEvent.detail)});
}
```